# Map bindings for google.longrunning.Operations/GetOperation to any Uri template

Tags: php

I could not map bindings for google.longrunning.Operations/GetOperation to any Uri template. How do I solve this problem?

```
Bindings: Array
(
    [name] => projects/project/operations/b1ffb4a5c0037742
)
UriTemplates: Array
(
    [0] => /v1/{name=operations/*}
    [1] => /v1/{name=locations/*/operations/*}
)
```

Comment: already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55903626/google-longrunning-operation-cant-map-binding-to-any-uri-template

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed after updating this vendor file

image_annotator_rest_client_config.php

['method' => 'get','uriTemplate' => '/v1/{name=projects/*/operations/*}'],